# Readonly spread array in tuple

Tags: typescript

I have some TypeScript code that I mean not to be executed, but it does, why?

```
let a:[boolean, ... readonly string[]] = [true, '1', '2', '3'];

a[0] = false;
a[1] = 'one'; //no error, but it should be error
```

Comment: What makes you think that there should be an error? You can have partially immutable array in ts/js. Either whole list is immutable or not.

Comment: This is an interesting question.  I think that perhaps that something like  `[… readonly X[]]` was never anticipated and it doesn’t actually do anything different from `[…X[]]`, but I don’t have a source for that.  The existing comments and answers here are asserting this but I don’t see any authoritative info.  I’m wondering if someone wants to open an issue in GitHub asking to clarify the situation.

Comment: @jcalz i will try to ask question)

Comment: Please note that there is an issue template you should fill out; you're either making a feature request (e.g., please support partially readonly tuple types) or a bug report (e.g., don't allow `...readonly string[]`).

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code doesn't produce an error is that the type of `a` is immediately reduced by the compiler to the fully-mutable type `[boolean, ...string[]]`, despite your annotation:

```
let a: [boolean, ... readonly string[]] = [true, '1', '2', '3'];

type A = typeof a;
// type A = [boolean, ...string[]]
```

And therefore none of the elements of `a` are read-only. So that's the answer to the question as asked.

---

The obvious follow-up question is "*why* does it get reduced to a fully mutable type?".  Unfortunately I can't find any authoritative source for this, so anything I could say here would be speculation.  Here it comes:

The type `[T, ...A]` is the type you get when you [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) an array of type `A` into the end of an array literal that starts with a value of type `t`. The fact that the following function compiles with no error is evidence of this:

```
function f<T, A extends readonly any[]>(t: T, a: A): [T, ...A] {
    return [t, ...a]
}
```

And if I have a read-only string array and spread it to the end of an array literal, the resulting array will not be read-only:

```
const strs: readonly string[] = ["x", "y"]
const result = f(true, strs);
// const result: [boolean, ...string[]]
```

So that's my guess. If anyone finds any canonical source (e.g., TS doc or GitHub issue) that confirms or refutes this, I'd be interested to know about it.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2#code/DYUwLgBAhgXBDaAjA9s0UB2AaCA6fEATiFACbIbACeEAzmIQJYYDm8AuuxALwIMCuIHAHIAjMJEAmCRGEBmYewDcAWABQ6sFQAOICAEEeELbuQAzaKrUB6a8Z17DvJKnTY8+ek1Yd269VDwAAxcvGZQwLQgVoGiobIUIMJKELYYyBAghITIhDiI-JCMkLQAFsj8wKQQiHpZOYT+amb8GADGYIwUEGYAPAAqOIYgAB5gIBiktEQk5JQ0mFQcAHwAFGBwg9Bw+gCUcPBb+Lj6XADe6hBXM2D8hBh8OMdQfmoAvuptFPR0DLRwxDIFGov28bHi8AARCNIThIVRIa8vhgfsRaJVIGF1oRBDgvLRdlZbBBkaiQOjgBsECg0CR3McvMxwa8gA)

Answer (score 0):

It works because `readonly` is only the individual elements themselves. The array itself is still mutable.

If you did

```
let a:readonly [boolean, ... readonly string[]] = [true, '1', '2', '3'];

a[0] = false; // error
a[1] = 'one'; //error
```

then, yes, it errors because you've marked the array itself as readonly, not just some of its values.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote: Here's a playground of the above being demonstrated: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBATiCGAmB7AdsAnhWAuA2gI0UVFmQBoIA6K6OJVDAZzCgEtkBzHAXS4gF4IOZgFcQ5AOQBGcRIBMMiOIDM4rgG4AUBtg4ADLwEAzWMAYhNOyQcUoQ4tRAD0jiCChREUIA

Answer (score 0):

Spreading an array/tuple just orderly lists out the element of that array.

It just plucks out the values from the array without actually modifying/transferring the inferred characteristics

```
let xs = [1,2,3,4]

let ys = [...xs] // [1,2,3,4]
```

Hence when we do

```
let a:[boolean, ... readonly string[]] = [true, '1', '2', '3'];
```

We are just saying pluck all the values from the `readonly string array` and not that make the values as `readonly`.

Thus the behavior.